# Show element in different page using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a 2 pages.

1. Master Page
2. Default page (inherited from master page)

I have a menu in the master page & I need to click some menu item & when it's clicked I need some element (span) to be visible in default page.

There's no error in below code, but the expected result did not happen.

`MasterPage`:

```
 <li id="lgbtn" style="float:right"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
 <script>
        $('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {
            $('span4').show();//<-- this span is in Default page
        });
    </script>
```

`Default.aspx`:

```
<div class="span4" style="visibility:hidden">
   <form  name="form-area"  class="form-area" runat="server">
     //Some content here
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)you missed `dot` for class

2)you `visiblity` style so show didn't work in that case so please use css style `visibility visible`

```
$('.span4').css("visibility" , "visible");
```

try this

```
  $('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {
       if($('.span4').is(":visible")){
       $('.span4').css("visibility" , "hidden");
       }
       else{
        $('.span4').css("visibility" , "visible");
       } 
    });
```

another way

```
 <div class="span4" style="display:none">
    $('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {
           if($('.span4').is(":visible")){
           $('.span4').show();
           }
           else{
            $('.span4').hide();
           } 
        });
```

simplest way to do you also change in html

```
 <div class="span4" style="display:none">

  $('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {

           $('.span4').toggle();

        });
```

first you know about what is the difference between visibilty and display in css

> **visibility: hidden** hides the element, but it still takes up space in
>   the layout.
>
> **display: none** removes the element completely from the document. It
>   does not take up any space, even though the HTML for it is still in
>   the source code.
>
> You can see the effect of these style properties on this page. I
>   created three identical swatches of code, and then set the display and
>   visibility properties on two so you can see how they look.

Comment: Good.How do i Visible false again in next click ?

Comment: $('.span4').css("visibility" , "hidden");

Comment: @sudharsan: so you understood toggle works and says it is the simplest way..!! good..!! thats what i answered and you said it will not work..!!

Answer (score 2):

In JQuery if you want to get element based on class then you have to write syntax like below

$('.ClassName')

and to get element based id then

$('#ControlId')

Answer (score 2):

Jquery's .show is the same as saying display: block;

In order to solve this you could change it using

```
$('.span4').css("visibility" , "visible");
```

Or you could change the html to be as follows:

```
<div class="span4" style="display: none;">
   <form  name="form-area"  class="form-area" runat="server">
     //Some content here
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Good.How do i Visible false again in next click ?

Comment: TechGuy you may use the toggle function in order to swap the show property on and off based on its current status.

You can read more about it here:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

use

like

```
<script>
        $('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {
           $('.span4').css("visibility" , "visible");
        });
    </script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsQkZ/)

[**UPDATED DEMO WITH toggle()**](http://jsfiddle.net/nsQkZ/1/)

For toggle() use

[*toggle*](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

**html**

```
<li id="lgbtn"  style=""><a href="#">Login</a></li>
<div class="span4" style="display:none">asds</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#lgbtn" ).click(function() {
        alert("clicked");
           $('.span4').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Good.How do i Visible false again in next click ?

Comment: @TechGuy: visible false in next click of login ??

Comment: use $(".span").toggle();

Comment: @sudharsan:it works but it should be display none..!! try my demo and edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Try to use that code:

```
$('#lgbtn').live('click', function (e) {
        $('.span4').show();//<-- this span is in Default page
    });
```

Comment: Good.How do i Visible false again in next click ?

Comment: Use the toogle function without any parameters instead of show